# How to set header values in API call

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Getting 401 status even passing application id and key for each request

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',});

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
 options.headers.set('Accept', "application/json,text/xml ");
 options.headers.set('X-AYLIEN-NewsAPI-Application-ID', "ff6**d33");
 options.headers.set('X-AYLIEN-NewsAPI-Application-Key', "b7445d942********7c06e");
```

API Call:

```
  this.http.get(url)
    .subscribe(res => {
    resolve(res.json());
    }, (err) => {
    reject(err);
    });
    });
    }
```

This is the code i am using to set value in header but it is not working.

Comment: Where is your code where you calling your API with this headers?

Comment: This is what perfectly working for me: this.headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'appInstanceCode': '' + this.appCode, 'token': '' + this.token });

Comment: Using HttpHeaders class

Comment: but new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }) is not taking httpHeader.. @PrashantPimpale

Comment: i am new to this. please help me

Comment: Is that above code is all?

Comment: @ranjana is your problem resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getDataGetAuth(url) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
         options.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
         options.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ sessionStorage.getItem("token") );

        this.http.get( MainURL+url,options)
        .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res.json());
        }, (err) => {
            reject(err);

        });
    });
}
```

This code is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

In Service:

First :

> import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

```
private url = "your_url";
private headers: any;

this.headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
'your_key': '' + value, 'your_key': '' + value });

getRecords(): Promise<any>{
    const url = `${this.url}/end_point`;
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers })
    .toPromise()
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

In Component consume your service API call like:

```
 this.your_service_obj.getRecords()
      .then(response => {
      // console.log(response)
      },
      err => {
      })
```

Comment: glad it helps you!